# Использование Node.JS на локальном сервере

Tags: node.js

Хочу понять **принцип** работы с `Node.JS`.

1. Скачал с официального сайта пакет установки (система Win64).
2. Установил себе на компьютер.

Создаю в диске **С** файл `test.js` следующего содержания:

```
var beep = require('beeper');
beep();
```

Пишу в командной строке три строчки (выполняя последовательно):

```
cd C:/
npm install beeper
node test.js
```

Должен прозвучать одиночный звук. Звучит. Всё работает.

Что делать дальше? У меня стоит локальный сервер. Есть отдельный сайт. В нём есть HTML и JS файлы. Как работать с Node.JS через эти файлы? Меня интересует сам принцип работы, как это делается. Поскольку через командную строку, пользоваться сайтом как-то неудобно, сами понимаете. Как прикрутить Node.JS к сайту и его файлам? Чтобы не через командную строку работать, а через сайт на локальном хостинге. Первый раз сталкиваются с такой задачей, не знаю с какой стороны подойти.

Моя основная цель - сделать чат на Node.JS с сохранением сообщений в БД. Но об этом пока думать рано. Прежде нужно понять основные принципы.

Comment: Вообще вам нужно посмотреть какие то уроки или гайды почитать. Но для быстрого старта можете глянуть http://expressjs.com Там есть примеры

Answer (score 2):

**Node.js** - это **V8** плюс **libuv**.

**V8** - это движок **JavaScript**. Он позволяет выполнять код написанный на языке **JavaScript**. Этот движок используется в браузере **Chrome**

**libuv** (Unicorn Velociraptor Library) - это библиотека асинхронного ввода/вывода на основе **цикла событий** (**event loop**).

**Node.js** позволяет выполнять **JavaScript** не только в браузере (как это было задумано при создании языка), но и на сервере. То есть используя **Node.js** вы можете создать собственный сервер, который будет общаться с браузером используя протокол **HTTP**, а так же выполнять серверные процессы - работать с сервером баз данных, работать с удаленными серверами, обрабатывать какие-нибудь данные и т.п.

**Node.js** может вам целиком заменить ваш существующий локальный веб-сервер. **Node.js** будет раздавать ваши HTML и JS файлы.

Для создания чата вам нужно написать код, который будет работать как на стороне сервера (**Node.js**), так и на стороне клиента (браузер). Но основной плюс от использования **Node.js** - это то, что код для обеих частей вы пишите на одном языке - **JavaScript**.

Что бы разобраться с основами начните с сайта [NodeSchool](https://nodeschool.io/ru/)